# Java Spring MongoDB @query with regex

Tags: regex, spring, mongodb

Anybody can help me with transforming following query:

```
@Query("{$or:[{'name':?0},{'synonims':?0}]}")
Stream<Examination> customFind(String str);
```

into query with regex that would allow case insensitive requests as per Spring documentation:

EXACT (case-insensitive) `{"firstname" : { $regex: /^firstname$/, $options: 'i'}}`

Following does not work:

```
@Query("{$or:[{'name':{ $regex: '/^?0$/', $options: 'i' }},{'synonims':{ $regex: '/^?0$/', $options: 'i' }}]}")
```

Comment: Not sure, but try escaping the question mark `/^\?0$/`

Answer (score 0):

The character `?` is a special character in regex that means *optional*, like `a?` meaning that `a` might be there or not.

You have to escape it if you want to match it.

```
$regex: '/^\?0$/'
```

And if you need to put it literally, then you would need two back slashes:

```
$regex: '/^\\?0$/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove both the / from your query as you are passing regex as string (not the single quotes your regex value). More specifically following query will give you desired results:

```
@Query("{$or:[{'name':{ $regex: '^?0$', $options: 'i' }},{'synonims':{ $regex: '^?0$', $options: 'i' }}]}")
```

Javascript treats values enclosed in / as regex (/pattern/), wrapping it with single quotes makes it a string. Either of the following would work:

```
{ <field>: { $regex: /pattern/, $options: '<options>' } }
{ <field>: { $regex: 'pattern', $options: '<options>' } }
{ <field>: { $regex: /pattern/<options> } }
```

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#mongodb-query-op.-regex